# Image created in PHP is shown only if accessed with direct link

Tags: php, html, json, php-gd

I created a script on localhost which shows some stats from a `json`. If I access the direct link, everything is fine. If I tried to add that link to an  HTML image tag, the page is rendered white with no image.

What could be the problem? If you need the code, I'll edit later (I'm on mobile).

---

Could this error be due to the usage of `localhost`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="localhost/banner.php?id=STEAMID&bg=bg1&rank=0"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

---

I can see the image if I access `localhost/file.php?id=NUMERIC_STEAMID`, but if I add this line `<img src="" />` the page remains empty.

```
<?php
include("settings.php");

// GET CULOURS
if(!isset($_GET['culoare_titlu'])) $color_title = "FFC200"; else $color_title = substr($_GET['culoare_titlu'],0,6);
if(!isset($_GET['culoare_info'])) $color_info = "FFFFFF"; else $color_info = substr($_GET['culoare_info'],0,6);
if(!isset($_GET['bg'])) $bg = "bg1"; else $bg = $_GET['bg'];
if(!isset($_GET['rank'])) $rank = "0"; else $rank = (int)$_GET['rank'];
// Get Userid
if(!$_GET['id'] || !ctype_digit($_GET['id'])){ 
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=index.php">';
}
$steamid = $_GET['id'];

// Get username, avatar , kills, deaths and played time
$noDigit = 0; 
$hoursPlayed = 0;
$weHaveCSGO = 0;
$nullJson = 0;
if(ctype_digit($steamid)){
    $noDigit = 1;
    $uuser = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=".$steamauth['apikey']."&steamids=".$steamid."";
    // cURL for this 
    $ch_1 = curl_init($uuser);
    curl_setopt($ch_1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
     curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch_1);
     // execute all queries simultaneously, and continue when all are complete
    $running = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
        $content = curl_multi_getcontent($ch_1);
    } while ($running);
    $response_1 = curl_multi_getcontent($ch_1);
    $user = json_decode($response_1, true);
    // Until here
    if(isset($user['response']['players'][0]['steamid'])){
        $nullJson = 1;
        $customURL = $user['response']['players'][0]['profileurl'];
        $username = $user['response']['players'][0]['personaname'];
        $avatar = $user['response']['players'][0]['avatarfull'];
        $privacy = $user['response']['players'][0]['communityvisibilitystate'];
        if($privacy == 3){
            $getGames = simplexml_load_file($customURL."games?tab=all&xml=1");
            foreach($getGames->games->game as $game){
                if($game->appID == "730"){
                    $weHaveCSGO = 1;
                    $hoursPlayed = $game->hoursOnRecord;    
                }
            }
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($customURL."?xml=1");
            $customMessage = $xml->stateMessage;
            if($weHaveCSGO == 1){
                $ggame = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=".$steamauth['apikey']."&steamid=".$steamid."";
                // cURL for this too
                $ch_2 = curl_init($ggame);
                curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                $mh = curl_multi_init();
                curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch_2);
                // execute all queries simultaneously, and continue when all are complete
                $running = null;
                do {
                    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
                    $content = curl_multi_getcontent($ch_2);
                } while ($running);
                $response_2 = curl_multi_getcontent($ch_2);
                $game = json_decode($response_2);
                foreach($game->playerstats->stats as $stats){
                    if($stats->name == "total_kills"){ $total_kills = $stats->value ; }
                    else if($stats->name == "total_deaths"){ $total_deaths = $stats->value ; }
                    else if($stats->name == "last_match_favweapon_id"){ $last_match_weapon = $stats->value ; }
                    else if($stats->name == "total_rounds_played"){ $total_rounds_played = $stats->value; } 
                    else if($stats->name == "total_wins"){ $total_wins = $stats->value; } 
                }
            }
        }

// Convert weaponID to weaponName

// This function just convert weaponID to weaponName so i removed from here

    }
}

$rank_image = "images/ranks/0.png";
$rankimage = ImageCreateFromPNG($rank_image);

// Create banner
switch($bg){
    case 'bg1':
    case 'bg2':
    case 'bg3':
    case 'bg4':
        $im = ImageCreateFromPNG("images/banners/$bg.png") or die ( 'GD Library not available atm.' );
    break;
    default:
        $im = ImageCreateFromPNG("images/banners/bg1.png") or die ( 'GD Library not available atm.' );
    break;
}

// Last match weaponID
$weapon = "images/weapons/hud/".$last_match_favweapon.".png";
$lmweapon = ImageCreateFromPNG($weapon);

//Culours for text
$color_green = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 183, 21);
$color_red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
$color_title = "0x$color_title";
$color_info = "0x$color_info";
$color_online = "0x24FF00";
$color_offline = "0xFF0000";
$color_black = "0x000000";
$color_bgreen = imagecolorallocate($im,0,160,0);

// Make some changes
$avatar = str_replace("https","http",$avatar);

// Get new sizes for avatar
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($avatar);
$newwidth = 90;
$newheight = 90;

// Load
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($avatar);

// Lenght username
if(strlen($username) > 21){
    $username = substr($username,0,21);
}

// Kills/Deaths Ratio
$kdr = @round($total_kills/$total_deaths,2);

// Win Ratio

$win = round((($total_wins/$total_rounds_played)*100),2);

//Let's create image, but first check user
if($noDigit == 0 || $weHaveCSGO == 0 || $nullJson == 0){
    imagettftext($im,20,0,140,60,$culoare_text_info,'fonts/arialbd.ttf',"This user doesn't exist !");
} else {
//Avatar
imagecopyresized($im, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
// Rank
imagecopy($im,$rankimage,96,3,0,0,imagesx($rankimage),imagesy($rankimage));
// Username
imagettftext($im,9,0,153,20,$color_info,'fonts/arialbd.ttf',$username);
// Status
if($customMessage == "Online"){
    imagettftext($im,7,0,290,20,$color_bgreen,'fonts/arialbd.ttf',"Online");
}
$cauta   = 'Last Online';
$cautare = strpos($customMessage, $cauta);
$cauta2 = 'In-Game<br/>Counter-Strike: Global Offensive';
$cautare2 = strpos($customMessage, $cauta2);
$cauta3 = 'In-Game<br/>';
$cautare3 = strpos($customMessage, $cauta3);
if ($cautare !== false) { 
    imagettftext($im,7,0,290,20,$color_red,'fonts/arialbd.ttf',"Offline");
} elseif($cautare2 !== false){
    imagettftext($im,7,0,282,20,$color_bgreen,'fonts/arialbd.ttf',"Playing CS:GO");
} elseif($cautare3 !== false){
    imagettftext($im,7,0,276,20,$color_title,'fonts/arialbd.ttf',"IN OTHER GAME");
}
// Fav weapons from last match
imagecopy($im,$lmweapon,107,30,0,0,imagesx($lmweapon),imagesy($lmweapon));
imagettftext($im,9,0,112,70,$color_title,'fonts/arialbd.ttf',$last_match_favweapon);
// K/D Ratio
imagettftext($im,11,0,166,52,$color_info,'fonts/arialbd.ttf',$kdr);
imagettftext($im,9,0,168,70,$color_title,'fonts/arialbd.ttf',"K/D");
// Win RATIO
imagettftext($im,11,0,216,52,$color_info,'fonts/arialbd.ttf',$win."%");
imagettftext($im,9,0,218,70,$color_title,'fonts/arialbd.ttf',"WIN %");
// Hours Played
imagettftext($im,11,0,276,52,$color_info,'fonts/arialbd.ttf',$hoursPlayed."h");
imagettftext($im,9,0,278,70,$color_title,'fonts/arialbd.ttf',"TIME");
}
header( 'Content-type: image/png' );
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Yes, we need the code.

Comment: What error do you get in the browser? Usually, if the image can't be load, the browser return the code error (500, 404 etc.) Also, how the `src` attribute look like in the `html` code?

Comment: Well ,that's strange. In browser i see image perfectly , no errors. If i try to add image link into HTML tag , page is empty.... no errors....i also have added error_reporting(E_ALL)

Comment: Please add the entire `html` code of your page. I've get the filling that there is the problem.

Comment: I just tested this . All i have it's <center> and <img> , including Doctype , head , title and body. Yes , head is closed

Comment: Again, please, add the entire html code of your page. (Edit your question). Do you have a public URL of this website so we can see it a live?

Comment: No. it's on localhost. I edit question right now.

Comment: `<img src="localhost/banner.php?id=STEAMID&bg=bg1&rank=0"></a>` remove the closing tag of the `a`. Also, please go to the `network` tab in the Chrome's DevTool and see all the requests, you can see the image's request too. What the status of this request? http://i.stack.imgur.com/0VTuP.png

Comment: It's function available in Firefox ? I don't use Chrome and i don't know. I try now

Comment: In FireBug http://i.stack.imgur.com/tsopA.png

Comment: Looks fine... http://aiurea.net/imagini/images/80683778770337303475.jpg

Comment: If you click on the line of the request and go to `response` tab, you can see the image. Can you? http://i.stack.imgur.com/nnXoo.png. Also, what about the closing `a` tag. Did you tried to remove it?

Comment: Oh, well. Yes. I have : Status Code:: 304 Not Modified

Comment: Try to debug your code during the request from the html and check if you have not error and if the headers returns OK. Maybe you can add the image with all the details about the request/response.

Answer (score 0):

localhost/banner.php?id=STEAMID&bg=bg1&rank=0
Should be http://localhost/banner.php?id=STEAMID&bg=bg1&rank=0

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are pointing to image file in wrong way

```
<img src="localhost/banner.php?id=STEAMID&bg=bg1&rank=0"></a>
```

it should be like this

```
<img src="http://localhost/banner.php?id=STEAMID&bg=bg1&rank=0"></a>
```

if you will not add `http://` protocol browser will read it as file/directory and will find your image like this

Assumming you are in `localhost` root directory

browser will load it as

```
http://localhost/localhost/banner.php?id=STEAMID&bg=bg1&rank=0
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/banner.php?id=STEAMID&bg=bg1&rank=0
```

When you direct access your image your browser read it as

```
http://localhost/banner.php?id=STEAMID&bg=bg1&rank=0
```